# Can't echo string .htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, html

This is my fault.. just found `Javascript` alert box!

I just add `htmlspecialchars`.

```
   $src = './imgs/flag.jpg'; 
   echo sprintf("<img alt=\"'.htmlspecialchars($name).'\" src=\"%s\" />", $src);
```

It does not works here found this on web source...

```
<img alt="Ken Lee="" src="\&quot;./imgs/flag.jpg\&quot;">
```

How to get this work.

Comment: *"This is my fault.. just found Javascript alert box!"* - I don't quite get this.

Comment: Why are you mixing concatenation and printf formatting? Use `alt=\"%s\"`

Answer (score 5):

Why the single quotes?

```
echo sprintf("<img alt=\"".htmlspecialchars($name)."\" src=\"%s\" />", $src);
```

Also, why not `printf()` instead?  Or why not:

```
echo "<img alt=\"".htmlspecialchars($name)."\" src=\"$src\" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo sprintf('<img alt="'.htmlspecialchars($name).' src="%s" />' , $src);
```

Mix of quotes got to be consistent 
I usually code php in single quotes so as to when i have to use print or echo the html uses the double quotes I saw you started you code with single quotes and then changed it up in the next line.